# Model Semantics: Is "real" data on a graph consider as a model?

Tags: graph, model, definition

At first this question seems elementary -- Is "real" data on a graph (xy coordinates) a model?  However here is my logic.  We know a model is an abstract representation of the real-world.  A graph is a model.  A mathematical formula is a model.  Most of the time the data output from these graphs, as we synonymously call a model, is "not real data" but it behaves similar.  Yet when you plot "real-time" data, it seems it would disqualify as a model because the output is real data similar to a real system.  So therefore it is the real system and not a representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on where you're coming from regarding the word model, since this is such a general word used all over.

Here's my take on it:

> We know a model is an abstract representation of the real-world.

It is but we ought to model with a purpose (a domain) in mind, and the model should help us work the domain and problems in the domain.

xy coordinates alone is probably not sufficient to be called a model, though one could make the case for it.

We would expect a model to have more capabilities, like finding the (as the crow files) distance between two items, or looking up the coordinates of a city, or navigating on city streets.

Without some interesting domain-specific behaviors, xy coordinates is more of a data structure or data type than a model.

Still, models come from data structures, so you might be thinking more behind the model than I can read in the question.

> Yet when you plot "real-time" data, it seems it would disqualify as a model because the output is real data similar to a real system. So therefore it is the real system and not a representation.

I might argue that it is not a model because there is no inherent domain problem solving capability, so it is more information (data) than a model.  If you were to combine the data with some capabilities to reason over the data, answer question pertinent to the domain, then I would see it as a model.

YMMV.